# How can I position an object start pos on the prefab start pos and same for end pos?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My prefab is built with 3 parts. Match Start, Cube , Match End :

[image: My match prefab]

What I did that if you click with the mouse on the Match Start or the Match End it will Instantiate another prefab clone. Now what I want to do is that the new cloned prefab will connect from the start or the end (both start and end are the red top and bottom parts on the match) with a different rotation.

For example something like :

[image: Example of how it should be]

Could be -90 on the Z the new match or 90 on the Z or 45 but not the same rotation like the last match since you will not see it it will be like one on the other one.

And then same logic when clicking on the new match end pos create a new match and so on.

The problem with my script now that it's creating a new match in some other place :

[image: The problem]

This is the script I'm using :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject matchPrefab;

    private Transform[] StartEndPos;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var match = Instantiate(matchPrefab);

        StartEndPos = match.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0f);

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePos);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.transform.tag == "Match Start" || hit.transform.tag == "Match End")
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < StartEndPos.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (StartEndPos[i].name == hit.transform.name)
                        {
                            var ClonedMatch = Instantiate(matchPrefab, StartEndPos[i].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Nothing there");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code, and it appears it works as it should - essentially. The logic might not work, but the instantiation does. However, can you post a picture of the Match prefab's transform values? It's possible your match prefab is not zeroed out. Make sure your prefab is Position (x,y,z) = (0f, 0f, 0f). If that's not the case, you'l will get super weird instantiations.